# Targeting specific li items

Tags: html, css, styling

Within my code I have list items like this;

```
<div id="content">
<ul class="kwicks">
<li id="home"><span class="header"></span>
```

Within the CSS I have styling like this;

```
 .kwicks li{
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding: 0;
   cursor: auto;
   }
```

However, I want to have a different background image for each list item and I'm having trouble targeting each one specifically. This snippet of code doesn't work.

```
.kwicks li #home{
   background: url(../images/slider_bg2.png) no-repeat left
   }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It might be just missing from your example, but make sure you close the `<li>` with a `</li>`

Comment: The code was just a snippet, all of the tags are closed in the real code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space `li #home`.write like this:

```
.kwicks li#home{
   background: url(../images/slider_bg2.png) no-repeat left
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector

```
.kwicks li #home {}
```

assumes the following markup-structure:

```
<ul class="kwicks">
    <li>
        <span id="home" class="header"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What you probably want is: (without a space betweeen li and #home)

```
.kwicks li#home {}
```

or even better (from a performance point of view):

```
#home {}
```

An ID is unique, so you don't need to specify classes or elements with it.